# for loop java increments

Tags: java, loops, math, formula, equation

I'm trying to do a math equation increment.

I'm starting at 2,500.
After the equation solves for `a`, `x3` becomes 2,800.
I need `a` to replace 2,500 with 2,800 so I can get the next answer 3,136.
After 3,136 it should be 3512.32 and so forth..
I don't know how to do the loop for this..

> essentially it'll increment more  than 300 after a few loops, but yes. basically like 50 ^ 3 =  125,00. which is 50 * 50 * 50. First it's 2500, then 2800, 3136, 3512, and then next is 3933, 4404, and so forth. That's 5 loops. I want to be able to do up to 100 loops.

```
public class Formula {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    double a = 2500;
    
    double x1 = 0;
    double x2 = 0;
    double x3 = 0;
    
    x1 = a / 2.5;
    x2 = ((x1 * 1.3) + (x1 * 1.5));
    x3 = x2;
    
    
        System.out.println(x3);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many times do you want it to run?  You just need to set `a = x3` and put all three lines in a `for` loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts just up to 100. how would i do that?

Comment: By "up to 100" do you mean "iterate 100 times, each time adding 300 to `a`?

Comment: @Bohemian essentially it'll increment more  than 300 after a few loops, but yes. basically like 50 ^ 3 =  125,00. which is 50 * 50 * 50. The code above is 2500, 2800, 3136, 3512, and then next is 3933, 4404, and so forth. That's 5 loops. I want to be able to do 100 loops.

Comment: How is the amount to increment calculated from the step number?

Comment: The difference of the value of `a` for each step is 300, 336, 376, 421, 471. The difference of those is 36, 40, 45, 50. What's the pattern? Are you sure that 3136 isn't supposed to be 3135, which would then form a consistent pattern of incrementing by 5 more each time?

Comment: @Bohemian 2800/2.5 = 1120. 1120 * 1.3 = 1456. 1120 * 1.5 = 1680. 1456 + 1680 = 3136. i'm just going by the calculator. not sure if there's an actual pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    double a = 2500 + i * 300;
    a = a / 2.5;
    a = ((a * 1.3) + (a * 1.5));
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Unnecessary variables removed.

Comment: Almost.. It's not supposed to add 300 all the time. Eventually when you get to 4404 after the 5th loop, the next answer is 4932. which is an increase of over 500.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a = 2500;
        int y;
        double x1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;
        double x3 = 0;

        System.out.println("enter amount of repetitions");
        y = kboard.nextInt();

        for( int i = 0; i<y; y++){

            x1 = a / 2.5;
            x2 = ((x1 * 1.3) + (x1 * 1.5));
            x3 = x2;
            x3= a;
        }
        System.out.println(x3);
    }
```

Comment: hey, i tried it. this is what pops up in the Console "enter amount of repetitions
10
2500.0
" it's just stuck at the first loop of 2500. didn't even give the answer lol 

Answer (score 0):

I combined both [Oscar Rautianinen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19832533/oscar-rautiainen) and [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) answers and made it into one code and it turned out almost what I needed! Only thing I can't figure out is if I wanted it to loop only 10 times. Instead, I have to put the "final" answer and it would give me my starting number up until the "final" answer of 10000. So if anyone knows how to fix that. Please answer/comment! Thank you

CODE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Equation {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        
    double a1;
    
    System.out.println("enter starting number");
    a1 = kboard.nextInt();
    
     while (a1 <= 10000) {
        
        a1 = a1 / 2.5;
        a1 = ((a1 * 1.3) + (a1 * 1.5));
        System.out.println(a1);
        }
    }
}}
```

FINAL RESULT:

```
enter starting number
2500
2800.0
3136.0
3512.3200000000006
3933.7984000000015
4405.8542080000025
4934.556712960002
5526.703518515203
6189.907940737028
6932.696893625471
7764.620520860528
8696.374983363792
9739.939981367446
10908.73277913154
```